# Unable to populate ListView with columns

Tags: c#

I created a ListView (Details) with 3 columns and I want to populate them but I get this error when I run the app inside Active Directory :     "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection". Parameter name: index

**UPDATE** : This code is now working without error (but I need to convert to datetime format.

```
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("physicalDeliveryOfficeName");
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("pwdlastset");

SearchResultCollection results = directorySearcher.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult result in results)
{
    string name = result.Properties["name"][0].ToString();
    string office = result.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"][0].ToString();
    string pwdlastset = result.Properties["pwdlastset"][0].ToString();

    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { name, office, pwdlastset});
    SearchResult.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Could you please ell me how to fix that ?

Comment: Did you try to debug the code and see if any value is null or not having data because sometimes that is the reason probably why you are getting an index error.

Comment: The LDAP query returns 3 users and they all have name, office and pwdlastset not null.

Comment: and where exactly does it crash? when you try to get name, office or value?

Comment: For test, I set only 1 column for ListView. When using attribute "name" only it worked. When using "office" it failed but I discovered that I should rather use "physicalDeliveryOfficeName" and it worked. When using PwdLastSet (and it is the correct LDAP attribute name), it failed here. So the issue is with PwdLastSet.

Comment: This is the attribute which gives me error (the 3 users get something similar like 131111023173214141) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679430(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because pwdLastSet needs the letters `L` and `S` in capital. Try this linq solution to avoid null exceptions:

```
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("physicalDeliveryOfficeName");
directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("pwdLastSet");

SearchResult.Items.AddRange(
    directorySearcher.FindAll().Where(x => x.Properties != null).Select(x => new ListViewItem(new string[] {
        x.Properties["name"] != null && x.Properties["name"].Any() 
            ? x.Properties["name"][0] 
            : String.Empty,
        x.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"] != null && x.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"].Any() 
             ? x.Properties["physicalDeliveryOfficeName"][0] 
             : String.Empty,
        x.Properties["pwdLastSet"] != null && x.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Any() 
             ? x.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0] 
             : String.Empty
    }))
);
```

Comment: Correct. Thanks a lot